# Help me with finding the equation of the Plane containing the points: p=(2,1,3), q=(1,0,1) and r=(2,-1,1).

Tags: analytic-geometry

Given three points p=(2,1,3), q=(1,0,1) and r=(2,-1,1), find the Cartesian equation of the plane containing those points.

Comment: Let the equation of the plane be ax+by+cz+d=0. Substitute your 3 points.Now you have 3 homogeneous equations in 4 unknowns.

Comment: 2X-2Y+2Z+8=0, that's the answer i got.

Comment: The three given points don't satisfy the equation you got. (I guess there's at least one sign error in your computation, because changing $+8$ to $-8$ would make $p$ and $r$ satisfy the equation. But $q$ still doesn't, so there's another error involved.)

Comment: By inspection, $x+y-z=0$

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate the direction vectors $\;\vec v:=\vec{pq}=q-p\;,\;\;\vec u=\vec{pr}=r-p\;$, then evaluate the vectorial product $\;(a,b,c)=\vec v\times\vec u\;$ , and this last is a normal vector to your plane, so your plane is $\;ax+by+cz+d=0\;\;$ . Finally, can you see how to evaluate $\;d\;$ ?

Comment: I think I got it, maybe just the final answer

Comment: Now I got -6X+2Y+2Z-4=0

Comment: @AntoniusMateusI That's wrong: the plane passes through the origin. Using the notation of my answer, I get $\;\vec v=(-1,-1,-2)\;,\;\;\vec u=(0,-2,-2)\;$ , and from here $\;\vec v\times\vec u=(-2,-2,2)\;$ , so your plane is $\;-2x-2y+2z+d=0\;$ , and substituting into this $\;q\;$ , for example, gives $\;d=0\;$ , so the plane is $\;x+y-z=0\;$ (I divided the above by $\;-2\;$ to make it nicer)

Comment: Now I got it, cool way

Comment: Usually easier and much quicker than solving a  $\;3\times3\;$ linear system of equations...